# how reduce repeating element xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
   <test-dump>
        <table-data>
            <table-max>1000</table-max>
            <table>
                <daten>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                </daten>
            </table>
            <table>
                <daten>
                </daten>
            </table>
            <table>
                <daten>
                </daten>
            </table>
            <table>
                <daten>
                </daten>
            </table>
            <table>
                <daten>
                </daten>
            </table>
            <table>
                <daten>
                </daten>
            </table>
            <table>
                <daten>
                </daten>
            </table>
            <table>
                <daten>
                </daten>
            </table>
            <table>
                <daten>
                </daten>
            </table>
        </table-data>    
    <test-dump>
```

I want to use XSLT  to produce the below output

the dump file is 6 G and i have to reduce it every group in the same level have the same value should be write 2 time first Time with the value second time write just from where to where is the same above value like this output

```
table-max = 1000
table(001)  = 
    daten = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
table(002)  = 
    daten = 
table(003 - 009)  = as above
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is that text format you have shown the exact output format you want to create? Does "same value" refer to the empty `daten` elements? Do you expect to process a 6 GB input XML with normal XSLT or are you looking for streaming with XSLT 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saxon EE with XSLT 3 and streaming should be able to process such a huge file with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes">
    
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" streamable="yes" use-accumulators="#all"/>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="table-no" as="xs:integer" streamable="yes" initial-value="0">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="table-data" select="0"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="table-data/table" select="$value + 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="max" as="xs:integer?" streamable="yes" initial-value="()">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="table-data/table-max/text()" select="xs:integer(.)"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:template match="table-data">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="table/daten/text()" group-adjacent=".">
            <xsl:if test="position() eq 1">
                <xsl:text>table-max = {accumulator-before('max')}&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:iterate select="current-group()">
                <xsl:param name="table-no" as="xs:integer" select="0"/>
                <xsl:param name="pos" as="xs:integer" select="1"/>
                <xsl:on-completion select="if ($pos gt 1) then ' - ' || format-integer($table-no, '001') || ') = as above&#10;' else ()"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() eq 1">
                        <xsl:text>table({format-integer(accumulator-before('table-no'), '001')}) = &#10;    daten = {current-grouping-key()}&#10;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="position() eq 2">table({format-integer(accumulator-before('table-no'), '001')}</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:next-iteration>
                    <xsl:with-param name="table-no" select="accumulator-before('table-no')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="position()"/>
                </xsl:next-iteration>
            </xsl:iterate>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you wanted to generate XML output you could change the above to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" expand-text="yes">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" streamable="yes" use-accumulators="#all"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="table-no" as="xs:integer" streamable="yes" initial-value="0">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="table-data" select="0"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="table-data/table" select="$value + 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="max" as="xs:integer?" streamable="yes" initial-value="()">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="table-data/table-max/text()" select="xs:integer(.)"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="table-data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="table/daten/text()" group-adjacent=".">
                <xsl:if test="position() eq 1">
                    <table-max>{accumulator-before('max')}</table-max>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:iterate select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:param name="table-start-no" as="xs:integer" select="0"/>
                    <xsl:param name="table-end-no" as="xs:integer" select="0"/>
                    <xsl:param name="pos" as="xs:integer" select="1"/>
                    <xsl:on-completion>
                        <xsl:if test="$pos gt 1">
                            <table range="{format-integer($table-start-no, '001')} - {format-integer($table-end-no, '001')}">
                                <daten>as before</daten>
                            </table>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:on-completion>
                    <xsl:if test="position() eq 1">
                            <table no="{format-integer(accumulator-before('table-no'), '001')}">
                                <daten>{current-grouping-key()}</daten>
                            </table>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:next-iteration>
                        <xsl:with-param name="table-start-no" select="if (position() eq 2) then accumulator-before('table-no') else $table-start-no"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="table-end-no" select="accumulator-before('table-no')"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="position()"/>
                    </xsl:next-iteration>
                </xsl:iterate>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Without streaming the code is much more compact but I don't know if it works with a 6 GB input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" expand-text="yes">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="#all"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="table-no" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="table-data" select="0"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="table-data/table" select="$value + 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="table-data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="table-max"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="table" group-adjacent="daten">
                <table no="{format-integer(accumulator-before('table-no'), '001')}">
                    <daten>{current-grouping-key()}</daten>
                </table>
                <xsl:if test="tail(current-group())">
                    <table range="{current-group()[2] ! accumulator-before('table-no') => format-integer('001')} - {current-group()[last()] ! accumulator-before('table-no') => format-integer('001')}">
                        <daten>as before</daten>
                    </table>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hallo @Martin Honnen
Thank you for your Answer. i try your Solution but its not work. i get just this value

1000 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
i try your solution on your Site 
"https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/" and its work why?

Comment: @MH2019, can you post a link to a fiddle where you have tried? I don't know which sample you used, if your are trying with xsltfiddle anyway and have any sample data there you can safely save and share then please do that and post the link to the fiddle in a comment.

Comment: @MH2019, I have just created https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ4j and it has the desired result, at least if I have interpreted the question and the result format well as being XML.

Comment: And https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ4j/1 and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ4j/2 are the other two suggestions.

Comment: i use Notepad++ with xslt plugin just for Test and its not work  of course on the website xsltfiddle its work perfect.
my question did i need to install  Saxon  on my Pc to get this code work ?

Comment: I posted XSLT 3 code so to use that you would need to install an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon 10 HE or Saxon-JS 2, or, to use streaming with huge input documents, even Saxon 10 EE. Altova also supports XSLT 3 so if you have or use e.g. Altova XML Spy you could also use that software or install it. Using XSLT 3 with Notepad++ is a different issue, I think it uses an XSLT 1 processor with that plugin you mentioned.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihre Hilfe.

Comment: @MH2019, did it work out to use the code against the huge 6 GB input? With Saxon HE or with EE?

Comment: i try it with java command but it`is not work because 2 reasons 1- i have this Value "&#0;" it is Null xslt can not read it.
 SXXP0003   Error reported by XML parser: Character reference "&#: Character reference "&#
i deleted it then i get other Problem 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
i try this parameter "java -Xmx1g " but its not work if i make 4g
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: A null character is not allowed in any XML document.

Comment: As for the memory options, how much memory does your machine have, do you run the 64bit version of Java?

Comment: i fixed memory i installed 64bit version. now i try fix null character
i our project we use eclapse wit some module i think its not support xslt version 3 we ask the developer if he can do something and i wait the answer. 
@Martin Honnen

Comment: can i make this code with xslt version 1? @Martin Honnen

Comment: [java]   line 6: Unzulässiges Attribut "expand-text".
     [java] ERROR:  'Nicht unterstütztes XSL-Element "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:for-each-group"'
@Martin Honnen

Comment: I can't help with conversion of XSLT 3 to XSLT 1, I would suggest to move to XSLT 3, given that it is the latest and current version of the W3C standard since 2017 and well supported. But anyway, processing 6 GB input XML documents is a challenge with any XSLT version, unless you can use XSLT 3 and streaming. For that I posted a suggestion.